# Search for text in shapes

Tags: excel, vba, search, text

I want to search text in shapes on Excel and I found the following code in excel.tips.net

```
Sub FindInShape1()
    Dim rStart As Range
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sFind As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim Response

    sFind = InputBox("Search for?")
    If Trim(sFind) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Nothing entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rStart = ActiveCell
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
        If InStr(LCase(sTemp), LCase(sFind)) <> 0 Then
            shp.Select
            Response = MsgBox( _
              prompt:=shp.Name & vbCrLf & _
              sTemp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "Do you want to continue?", _
              Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Continue?")
            If Response <> vbYes Then
                Set rStart = Nothing
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "No more found"
    rStart.Select
    Set rStart = Nothing
End Sub
```

It works if I search for a word that is in a shape near the top of the worksheet.
However, the worksheet is quite large, and if I search for something in the middle or bottom, I get error;

> Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)': The specified Value is out of
> range

I can choose to debug, and doing so highlights the line of code

```
sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

I'm using Excel 2010.

Thank you for your help,

Mattice

Comment: Hmm does every shape contain text?

Comment: @findwindow `shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text` will cause an error for most shapes... without `On Error Resume Next` I'm not sure how to run it without error-messages

Comment: I have tried to change 

shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text 

to

shp.TextEffect.Text

and it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is NOT an answer (but too much for a comment)

Please try this and check if the error still pops up:

```
Sub testForError()
  Dim shp As Shape, i As Long
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print i & " " & shp.Type
    Debug.Print i & " " & shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Debug.Print i & " " & shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
  Next
  Debug.Print "finished"
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
pls try it and tell me if errors pop up :)

```
Sub FindInShape1()
  Dim shp As Shape
  Dim sFind As String
  Dim sTemp As String
  sFind = InputBox("Search for?")
  If Trim(sFind) = "" Then MsgBox "Nothing entered": Exit Sub
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    Debug.Print shp.TopLeftCell.Address
    sTemp = ""
    sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    If Len(sTemp) Then
      If InStr(1, sTemp, sFind, 1) Then
        shp.Select
        If MsgBox(shp.Name & vbCrLf & sTemp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, "Continue?") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
      End If
    End If
  Next
  MsgBox "No more found"
End Sub
```

Comment: I ran it, and it didn't seem to do anything noticeable. then I ran the original code, and the error was still there. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @MatticeVerhoeven there should be a lot of text in the direct window of your VBA-window... the last output should be the "finished"... that tells us that there is a different problem...

Comment: I'm quite new to VBA sorry, I'm not sure what the direct window is. Also, should I run just the code above, or include it into the original code?

Comment: @MatticeVerhoeven as an extra macro... inside the VBA-window go to "View =>> Direct Window" or just press Ctrl + G... pls try the new code as an extra macro (i still need to know if the error pops up and the last output before it crashes)...

Comment: Yup I ran as an extra macro, there was a lot of text followed by "finished" in the direct window. Then I ran the original code again and got the same error.

Comment: it worked!! Thank you very much. Is there a way to make it not case sensitive though?

Comment: @MatticeVerhoeven i changed the `instr`-line to `If InStr(1, sTemp, sFind, 1) Then`... it now shout not be case sensitive anymore

Comment: @MatticeVerhoeven still... you need to know it does a specific check... having a smart-art with lots of text, they won't be checked... if you find a situation where it doesnt find a match it should, just ask and i'll change the code so it does... (there are countless paths where the text could be and it isn't possible to check all in a simple way)

Answer (score 0):

You forget that you must put "set" before assigning any shape variable.

```
Set sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

Comment: That line of code is capturing a `String` with the text within the shape, not the object, so `Set` is not appropriate here.